# How can I restore the iPad frame around iOS Simulator 5.1?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

With Xcode 4.3.1, Apple ships the new iOS 5.1 Simulator. Unfortunately, it looks like when you run iPad hardware, there's no longer the iPad frame around the sim window. Does anyone have any idea how to restore that frame? I often use the simulator to demo features to others via screen sharing, and it looks much better when it's in the iPad frame. Thanks in advance.

Interestingly, btw, there's no longer a `frame.png`. Instead, now within iOS Simulator's package, you only find: `./Contents/Resources/frame_1only_.png`

Comment: Dunno, but I bet there's a market for a Mac app that puts up an window that looks like an iPad bezel with a hole for the simulator window to show through.

Comment: A developer I work with is upset about this as well... I hope a solution will present itself.

Comment: If you're a registered Apple developer, file a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com and tell them to make the bezel (or frame) an ***option*** that can be turned on & off by developers. The more people who ask for this, the more likely it is Apple will give us what we want with our tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Xcode 4.2.1 from the dev center... other than that, there's nothing you can do about it.  Besides, I rather like the new minimalistic simulator.  (BTW, there is a rationale behind this: the new retina simulator is just too big to provide a good bezel image).

EDIT (to address the core of the problem): Even if you could find a suitable bezel image, how could you edit the internals of the simulator?  My proposal is: find an old Xcode with the proper sim, or mod the simFinger application to include an iPad frame (to my knowledge, it only works with the iPhone sim), and iPad dimensions.  Available here: https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger

EDIT 2: As it turns out, it does support the iPad, and bezel!

Comment: The problem was that I could not use an iPad 3 for development with Xcode 4.2.1, because it didn't have the debugging libs and symbols it needed. And while it's potentially fair to say that a retina-based iPad can't show a bezel, it's silly for Apple to say that a standard def one cannot, given that an iPhone still can...

Comment: The new iPad resolution is so huge already... the bezel is small in comparison.  It should be an option, especially considering you can scale the simulator.

Comment: I'm not saying that you can't still have Xcode 4.3 for development (beware, every install of Xcode will ask if you want to remove the old one), but just use the Xcode 4.2 sim for screen casts and such.  The only other thing I can think of is modding the simFinger application.

Comment: It'd be great to find a better solution, but for now, this one's the best. SimFinger doesn't fit too well on my 15" MBP screen, though.. :-(

Comment: HAHA, imagine how bad it is on my little 13" MBP!  Luckily, this thing hooks up to the 54" plasma a little too easily ;P

Comment: I can't get SimFinger to support the iPad simulator with Xcode 4.3.2. Has anyone had success?

Answer (score 6):

The frame disappears if the simulator + frame does not fit on your screen. If I move it to my big external monitor, switch to iPhone and back to iPad, I have the frame again.

Comment: Same for me.  The frame appears with the simulator in portrait mode on my 1920x1200 display but the frame will not appear with the simulator in portrait mode on my 1920x1080 display.

Comment: Fwiw, the iPad simulator with the frame in portrait mode is 854x1110.  The frame adds 86 pixels to each direction.

Answer (score 3):

As everyone said, make sure your simulator zoom is set to 100% by using CMD-1.

With the new retina resolution, you need to have a Retina Macbook to get it to work. You have to set your display resolution to max, and reset the simulator. This will then show the frame around both the iPad and iPad Retina simulators.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or a legitimate workaround, but if you are using the iOS 5.1 simulator, and go to Hardware > TV Out - turn on any of the options (uncheck disabled), the frame suddenly appears around the device.

Again... don't know if that will stick in future versions of xCode, but it worked for me for now!

Comment: Worked for me in iOS simulator 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

It appears it is looking at whether or not there is adequate screen resolution to display the bezel. For example, I have a 17" Macbok pro that I develop on (1920x1200 resolution). When I launch an iPad development project and the suimulator comes up on my Macbook pro's desktop, no problem, the bezel shows. But let's say I then drag it over to my external monitor which is 1920x1080, then quit and relauinch the simulator... it comes up without a bezel.

My co-worker who has a Macbook Pro 13" (lower resolution), never sees the bezel. I suspect the newer retina Macbook Pros will always show a bezel.

This is of course, al pertaining to the regular, non-retina iPad simulator. I am not sure if given adequate screen resolution, the iPad retina simulator would show a bezel or not?

Answer (score 0):

For me, in the iOS simulator, clicking on: 
Hardware -> Device -> iPhone (not the retina ones).

and then:
Window -> Scale -> 100% fixed the problem, and the frame reappeared.

On my work 13inch MBP, I can see the frame only with this setting.

Answer (score 0):

CMD + 1 and CMD + 2 keyboard shortcuts toggle the simulators view mode. Depending on the device, retina or non retina, you will see the bezel if your screen resolution can accomodate it.

Answer (score 0):

Window->Scale->100% did the trick for me... when it gets set to 75% it loses the frame