# Is there a different way to view the iOS Simulator in Xcode 5 / Am I viewing my button correctly?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, ios-simulator

So I'm doing the Ray Wenderlich tutorials on iOS, and I'm doing the button tutorial. When I run the app, I get something that looks like this:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. I often see simulators show up in the form of an actual iPhone and was wondering if that was possible, or if that rectangle is the only way to view it?
2. The reason I'm asking is when I connected the button to an action (It says 'Pressed!'). So, is it supposed to show up in the box (bottom right) only, or should it should up on the simulator itself- mimicking what the user would see on-screen?

Comment: Up in the upper left, just to the right of the > run button, is a double-ended button.  The left end lets you select which build you run, the right end lets you select the simulator you use.  Make sure you've selected the iPhone/iPad version you want to simulate.  Also be aware that the "Retina" iPad will show without frame (because it's too big to fit, even without the frame).

Comment: Thanks. This app is meant for iPhone, but the only options I have for iPhone is retina, and when I run it with that I get that bland rectangle without the iPhone outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question: Probably a problem with screen size. See also here [How can I restore the iPad frame around iOS Simulator 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756327/how-can-i-restore-the-ipad-frame-around-ios-simulator-5-1)

The output seen in the screenshot is produced with NSLog and won't be seen on the device. You need to add an UILabel or such and set its text.

Comment: So if the "Pressed!" is only supposed to show up after the user clicks on the button I still need to add the label?

Comment: Yes, though there are many other solutions which you could use. but in the beginning that is simplest.

Answer (score 0):

In the Simulator menu, try selecting Window then Scale and go to 50%.  The retina models are far too big on my screen.  Also, the old iOS 6 simulator with standard iPhone did look like a real phone, so examples from a while ago will look different.

If you want to support iOS 6.x, you can load it into Xcode.  From Xcode main menu, select Xcode and then Preferences, and go to the Downloads tab.